# Start Outlook VSTO Add-In as a Custom Action in a Rule

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin

I have a project where I need to save a table of data in an email from a certain account into a SQL table. I wrote an Outlook add-in using C# and it works perfectly when Outlook starts up. What I need is to create a rule so that when an email arrives, it will start the add in. I have tried to create a rule to do this but when I get the the Select Custom Action window, nothing is in the drop down. Is it possible to start an add-in as a custom action? If so, how is it done? Should I be looking at another way to do this project?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a way to do what I wanted with an add-in and a rule and I was running out of time. My solution was a console app that runs every few minutes. I used this example and added my code where needed. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310259